# How can I use @ symbol and a string variable in the same C# string assignment?

Tags: c#, string, literals

Up till now I've been using the following connection string:

`public static String connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ahmad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\DBtestApp1\DBtestApp1\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";`

However, since the MDF file is in the same directory as the EXE running itself, and since this directory can change, I now was to retrieve the current directory using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` ..

The problem is, a string assignment such as this does not work:

`connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"" + currentDirectory + "TestDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";`

where `currentDirectory` holds the output of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` ..

So whats the solution ?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the `static` field like that? From where are you doing so? Post some code.

Comment: Define "does not work"... You get a compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should actually work, but depending on the return value of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` your path might be broken.

Instead of concatenating the path within your string, you should use `Path.Combine()` provided inside `System.IO` for this, which will handle additional/missing backslashes between the parts to be concatenated:

```
string DbFile = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "TestDB.mdf");
```

You should then be able to simply add this string to your full connection string, which might be done using `String.Format()` as well:

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"...AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated...", Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "TestDB.mdf"));
```

I haven't tried this, but shouldn't it work using just `.\TestDB.mdf` as the filename? Or does it have to be an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

you could always put that in the App_Data folder ( the place where it should ideally reside) and call it like this.

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TestDB.mdf;
```